# Создание очереди запросов при остутствии интернета

Tags: android, база-данных, kotlin

Столкнулся с такой задачей: Приложение сканирует штрихкод и отправляет запрос на сервер, для проверки наличия такого в БД. Но возникает проблема при отсутствии интернета. Приложение может не достучаться до сервера и логика дальнейших действий будет не верна.
Можете ли подсказать или привести примеры кода с реализацией хранения очереди запросов, чтобы при отсутствии интернета запросы локально записывались и при возобновлении интернета эти запросы отправлялись на backend-сервер.
Буду рад и другим возможно более правильным решениям данной задачи.

Благодарю.

Comment: Не легче сразу подсказывать пользователю, что нет соединения, а не создавать очереди, которые возможно потом уже будут не нужны/о них забудут и т.п.

Comment: @Style-7 Насколько я понимаю, сложность в том, что есть действия например "подтверждение товара" и его нужно обработать сервером, но в это время интернет может быть либо плохим или же отсутсовать. И нужно дождаться его появления и не забыть сказать серверу. Кстати я не представляю как это можно реализовать. Вопрос и мне интересен

Comment: @WBLord а что там интересного? все пишется в локальную базу а при появлении соединения сервис пытается это пропихнуть, при подтверждении удаляется запись из локальной БД. скучно

Comment: Можешь привести пример кода. Я бы просто в корутине проверял постоянно состояние интернета, но мне кажется есть больее правильный метод